# Selecting an item from a combo box selenium driver with java

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to select an item from a combo box through selenium driver with java, but it didn't work.

This is my code...

```java
combo box list = {NIC, NAME, AGE};

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='views/div/select']/label")).sendKeys("NIC");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WebDriver there is separate Class ([Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)) is there to deal with Combo lists.

Use below logic to select options from pick list fields

```
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='views/div/select']"));

select.selectByVisibleText("NIC");
or
select.selectByIndex(0);
or
select.selectByValue("value");
```

Refer this [post](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/04/Select.html) for more info regarding Select class.

Comment: i got this error....Unable to locate element:
and i got this when i run this through selenium recording-  //div[@id='views']/div/select
value=label=NIC

Comment: You haven't looked at his answer properly. Notice he is **dropping** the `label` bit from the XPath. You **aren't.**