# Find WebElement by contents of a picklist using CSS: Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, combobox

In brief:

I am writing selenium tests in JAVA for a web application that does not have nice id's (i.e. they are dynamically generated).

My situation involves two comboboxes, or picklists if you prefer, with id's that look something like this (Note: In reality I may have hundreds of these on a page not just two.  Two is to keep it simple :) ):

```
elementOne id = '12345WORKRECORD678'

elementTwo id = '9876WORKRECORD5432'.
```

Using CSSSelectors I am able to get these elements in a List using this:

```
"...findElements(By.cssSelector("select[id*='WORKRECORD']");
```

Where * works similar to a "CONTAINS" statement.

The problem is that I don't know which element is which because I can't utilize the whole id.  All i know is that I have a List of picklists, but I can't easily choose the ONE that I want or need.  This is because the only consistent part of the id is "WORKRECORD", everything else is dynamic.

In order to know which element to utilized for my test I'm having to iterate through each item (option) in the picklist and make a decision based on what is there.  So something like this:

```
    //Get all picklists that contain string "WORKRECORD" in their id. 
    List<WebElement> picklists = 
        driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select[id*='WORKRECORD']"));

        //iterate through these picklists and get lists of options
    for(WebElement picklist : picklists)
    {
        //get all items/options in the picklist
        List<WebElement> options = picklist.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

        //Next go through each value and see if it is the one I want.  
        //If so, then I found my web element
        for(WebElement option : options)
        {
            if(option.equals(myValue))
            {
                myWantedWebElement = picklist;
                return myWantedWebElement;
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is this:

**Can I use CSS to locate a webElement based on a value that is found in the options?  For example, the psuedo-code would be like this:**

```
List<WebElement> picklists = 
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select[id*='WORKRECORD']:option[value contains 'myValue(s)']"));
```

Or will I just have to go with what I am doing?  Or is there something so much better that it will blow my mind, etc...

Thanks all and Cheers!

Comment: This link provides a much better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457503/selecting-an-item-from-a-combo-box-selenium-driver-with-java

Comment: @Richard - using the `Select` class would be very slow for this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is by using an XPath selector - locate by `option` value and then select it's parent `select`:

```
myWantedWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'WORKRECORD')]/option[.='optionvalue']/.."));
```

The following CSS selector will find the required `option`, but won't give you the `select` as CSS selectors donot have a parent selector - you cannot traverse back up the DOM tree.

```
select[id*='WORKRECORD'] > option:contains('optionvalue')
```

Comment: A better xpath to use can be `//select[contains(@id,'WORKRECORD') and option[.='optionvalue']]`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Faiz . The following `xpath` would also work :

```
xpath = //select[contains(@id,'WORKRECORD') and ./option[contains(.,'optiontext')]]
```

The above xpath will locate the **select tag** where **its id contains `WORKRECORD` and its child contains `optiontext` as its visible text**.